# Как спрятать часть элемента за экран?

Tags: android, вёрстка

Есть вот такой шаблон:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">
        </FrameLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

frame_1 - резиновый, он компенсирует место на экранах разной высоты.
Нужно, что бы frame_3 не полностью показывался на экране, а только на одну треть (20dp). Для того, что бы его увидеть полностью нужно проскролить экран.

Реализовать подобное поведение оставив frame_1 резиновым не получилось. Может кто нибудь уже сталкивался с подобной задачей и знает решение?
Может быть здесь нужен какой то другой лайаут?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением двух атрибутов:

- **android:fillViewport="true"** к ScrollView - заставляет LinerLayout растягиваться на всю высоту ScrollView
- **android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"** к LinearLayout - что бы спрятать 2/3 frame_3 под нижнею границу ScrollView

Рабочий код, теперь, выглядит следующим образом:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">
        </FrameLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```